# .NET Core API ToDoAPI does not work out of the box

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-code

I am trying to create a new API in VS Code. I am following the instructions on this page from MS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-vsc

The directions to get started are simple. With the Core SDK (2.1.4) installed, in the console I run this:

```
mkdir TodoApi
cd TodoApi
dotnet new webapi
```

That creates a new project which I should be able to run from either VS or VS Code. When I try running from either however, I get an error message that the "localhost:/5000" cannot be found.

I'm assuming this is a bug in the code the SDK generated but I'm not C# savvy. Has anyone else had this problem? Is there a resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that the browser has a white screen with "localhost:/5000 cannot be found" then yes, this is expected behaviour, the default launch settings for a solution is to go to the route of the project "/" but a web api does not fufill this contract (does not have an action for it).

If you want to test your web api go to

> http://localhost:5000/api/Values/Get

How do I know this?

In the web api project there is a folder called `Controllers` in there there is a class called `ValuesController` in that file you can see that the class has the attribute

`[Route("api/[controller]")]`

Please read here for more information on attribute routing

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing

I'll just state that the default way to get to this controller is `/api/Values` (removing the word Controller as is standard) and then call an action (could use any but I used get).

There are ways to override the default base url when you run your application, the settings that are used to launch and build your application are all under the `./vscode/` directory of your project, maybe have a play around.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Both of these solutions were relevant, however this one is the one that made the most sense to me and was the actual fix for me. Thanks to Balah also however, as he presented the fix as well, including information about the port that is helpful.

Comment: I should add that the tutorial DOES say this now, I'm just a moron and didn't read carefully. :(

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug... but not with the SDK, its with the tutorial - when you use `dotnet new webapi` it creates the project correctly, but likely using different ports.

If you go to the `Properties\launchsettings.json` file you will see what port you should be using. e.g.

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53096/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
```

Then you can navigate to `http://localhost:53096/api/values` to see it work.

Note that the root `http://localhost:[your port]/`will always return Not Found because that webapi template does not not have any routing setup for that.

The rest of the tutorial shouldn't have any other hiccups.

Comment: May be worth adding information on why the /api/values route works and the / route doesn't for clarity